# Is it possible to list all tags across all behat tests?

Tags: tags, behat

I have several hundred behat tests created by many people who used different tags. I want to clean this up, and to start with I want to list out all the tags which have been used so far.

Comment: Fellow reviewers: this is a self-answered one. It may look broad, but it is a user trying to share their discovery.

Comment: is this against a policy of stackoverflow? And others are free to answer this question with a better solution than the one I came up with?

Comment: Not against the  policy at all! Sharing your knowledge is encouraged; we even have a badge for upvoted self-answers. I posted the comment because some people voted to close the question. I encountered your question in the Close Votes review queue, where we don't see answers - only the question and the comments. So I posted the comment to make my fellow reviewers aware that this is a self-answered question. You did the right thing.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to answer my own question as it was something I could not find an answer to elsewhere.

I tried initially to use a custom formatter but that did not work.
https://gist.github.com/paulmozo/fb23d8fb436700381a06

Eventually I crafted a Bash command to suit my purposes

```
bin/behat --dry-run 2>&1 | tr ' ' '\n' | grep -w @.* | sort -u
```

This runs the behat command with `--dry-run` which does not execute the tests, merely outputs the steps so I can pipe them to another tool. The `2>&1` redirects the standard error to null (this is shell dependent). The `tr` tool breaks every word in the stream into a separate line. The grep searches for lines starting with the @ symbol. Finally `sort -u` sorts the list and returns the uniques.

This command takes about 15 seconds to run and did the job perfectly for me.